# matlab: get variable creation time

Tags: matlab, undocumented-behavior

I want to renew a variable if it is outdated - obviously this could be done with storing its creation time.

However - is there a (possilby undocumented) way of figuring out WHEN a variable in workspace was declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to know when a variable was created. [People have explored the array metadata in detail](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlabs-internal-memory-representation), and nobody has found any indication of creation time stamps.

Furthermore, such a data field has no uses in general, and therefore are unlikely to be implemented, as a time stamp would just take up memory without providing a benefit.

For the very few cases where such a time stamp would be useful, I’d recommend creating a class that behaves like a normal numeric array, but additionally carries a time stamp.

Comment: is there something like a console log for matlab internal commands? I guess the console log itself isn't really useful beyond if you define variables manually / yourself (in the console)

Comment: @user2305193: Do you mean the command history? I think that is only for interactive usage -- it logs the command that executes a function, not each of the lines of code inside that function. Also, I don't think that the command history keeps a time stamp for each command, but I might be wrong about that.